# Конструктор дочернего класса в PHP

Tags: php, ооп, наследование

При изучении ООП в PHP я не понял один момент: когда один класс наследует(расширяет) другой, он наследует все свойства и методы родительского класса? (это ведь так?), но доступ может получить лишь к public или protected свойствам/методам. Я поставил все свойства родительского класса private. Но когда я создаю конструктор  в дочернем классе, то чтобы определить для экземпляра дочернего класса при создании свойства, мне надо ещё и вызвать parent::__construct().Но ведь доступ к свойствам private может осуществиться лишь из данного класса, но не из дочернего, так почему parent::__construct() может получить к ним доступ? Он ведь вызывается именно из дочернего? У методов-родителей, вызываемых из дочерних классов есть особые привилегии, даже если они вызываются не из своего класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Официальная документация PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php)

> Область видимости свойства или метода может быть определена путем
>   использования следующих ключевых слов в объявлении: public, protected
>   или private. Доступ к свойствам и методам класса, объявленным как
>   public (общедоступный), разрешен отовсюду. Модификатор protected
>   (защищенный) разрешает доступ наследуемым и родительским классам.
>   Модификатор private (закрытый) ограничивает область видимости так, что
>   только класс, где объявлен сам элемент, имеет к нему доступ.

У вас в родительском классе обьявлен _construct, поэтому он имеет доступ к методам/свойствам в своей области видимости к закрытым элементам класса.

Comment: Переварил, в общем. Род. конструктор хоть и вызывается из дочернего и имеет доступ к приватным свойствам, но все же **влияет** на дочерний объект, давая возможность клиентскому коду при создании задать нужные свойства. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1):

> он наследует все свойства и методы родительского класса? (это ведь так?)

Да, он наследует все public/protected свойства и методы.

Не важно, что родительский конструктор вызывается из дочернего, так как он находится в родительском классе, то он имеет доступ к своим private свойствам и методам.

Comment: Да, он имеет доступ к своим закрытым свойствам, но тогда выходит, что дочерний класс наследует и private свойства, потому что если через родительский конструктор можно определить какое-либо свойство в дочернем классе, значит, что оно вообще-то имеется в дочернем классе, просто доступ к нему закрыт, а вы написали public/protected. Поэтому я немного запутался

Comment: @Muller ну разумеется внутри себя он имеет доступ - иначе как он сможет работать? private не дает явно обратиться к свойству, а не удаляет его нафиг из класса совсем

Comment: @Ипатьев я понял, спасибо.